# Invoke date picker component in flex mobile

Tags: apache-flex, datepicker, flash-builder, flex-mobile

**Problem:** I have to get date as input from user in flex mobile application.

**Question:** How to invoke date picker component from flex mobile application that selects some date from component and display the selected date in text input.

**Platform:** Flash Builder 4.6

Answer (score 1):

Use the DateSpinner class, you can put it in a popup or callout or whatever

http://devgirl.org/2011/11/17/flex-mobile-development-datespinner-sample-with-source/

Comment: Try putting it in a 
    <s:SpinnerListContainer>
       <s:DateSpinner/>
     </s:SpinnerListContainer>

Comment: Still displaying the same error of accessing null object reference. Error # 1009. I used following code

<s:SpinnerListContainer>
    <s:DateSpinner id="dt" displayMode="{rg.selectedValue}" /> 
   </s:SpinnerListContainer>

Comment: Make sure your radiobuttongroup is initialized, and has a selected value.  It will be null otherwise